# Angular 6 API URL with port is not called correctly. API port dissapears on angular prod mode

Tags: angular, nginx, amazon-ec2, angular6

I have an API URL, set as a global variable in my angular app:

```
API_URL: 'http://52.109.53.23:3001'
```

And all my API requests pass through this URL, and it works fine in development mode (`ng s`) but when I compile it for production (`ng build --prod`) and deploy on my ubunut nginx web server, the request fails, they are wrong, the **Api port number is missed**: this is the console output:

```
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://52.109.53.23/auth/sign_in"
```

If you notice the port has disappeared, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: is this value retrieved through `environment` type setup? most probably you only have the variable in environment.ts and not in environment-prod.ts or just forgot the port in the prod version

Comment: @jcuypers no, can you please tell how to do that. I just create a class (global.ts with API_URL as cons) and inject it in all services that I create. and it works fine in dev, but when I compile the request is made without the port number.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation.

```
ng build --prod
```

The **--prod** meta-flag engages the following build optimization features.

- Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compilation: pre-compiles Angular component
  templates.
- Production mode: deploys the production environment which **enables
  production mode**.
- Bundling: concatenates your many application and library files into a
  few bundles.
- Minification: removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional
  tokens. Uglification: rewrites code to use short, cryptic variable
  and function names
- Dead code elimination: removes unreferenced modules and much unused
  code.

The environments configuration is set in the angular-cli configuration file (angular-cli.json or angular.json in v6) which has two options by default: dev and prod

```
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

For v6+, angular.json environments are configured in configurations sections.

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

If you are using the same url for both enviroments then you should define it in both files

**src/environments/environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL: 'http://52.109.53.23:3001'
};
```

**src/environments/environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API_URL: 'http://52.109.53.23:3001'
};
```

In order to use the environments variables all you have to do is import the environment object as follows:

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

....

apiUrl = environment.API_URL;

....
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project you should have a folder 'environments' with two standard files: environment and environment-prod.ts.  in both of them you add whatever you need

```
export const environment = {
   server : 'http://<ip>:<port>'
}
```

later you reference it by

```
import { environment } from '<wherever it is>';
```

and then reference it by `environment.server`

when you perform a prod build environment-prod will be used in favor of environment

Comment: in my case server : 'http://<52.109.53.23>:<3001>', is correct in this way?